# Passing null to Function.call()

Tags: javascript

```
function outerFun(arg1, arg2, arg3){

    function innerFun(arg1, arg2){
        //do something
    }

    var innerArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    innerFun.apply(null, innerArgs);
}
```

As you can see i'm trying to call a function with a modified arguments array of a different function. The only way of doing this i can think of is using the apply() method and passing the sliced array. My question is, is there a different way of doing this? If there isn't then can i just pass null to apply() or is that considered bad practice?

Comment: passing null , referes THIS to window.

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Do you need this to be the global scope ? I'm afraid it's hard to answer without the innerFun function. I won't vote to close as I may have missed something but this question doesn't seem precise enough.

Comment: Does this not work? innerFun(arg2, arg3)

Comment: Why would you pass arguments to call?  How/why would you want your arguments to be "this".  The call function's first argument is what ```this``` is set to.  This line doesn't make sense to me.  MDN for Object.call is at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: This question is confusing.  It asks about Function.call(null) but doesn't use that in the code sample.   The title is asking one thing, the code says something else, and the text refers to the code which IMO is hard to understand.  Maybe I'm missing something and if so, I'll gladly be enlightened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, is there a different way of doing this?

No, [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) is the only method in JavaScript capable of running a function with an  array as arguments. However, you could still use the actual arguments and use the function:

```
function outerFunc(arg1, arg2, arg3){
    /* ... */
    innerFun(arg2, arg3);
    /* ... */
}
```

> If there isn't then can i just pass null to apply() or is that considered bad practice?

You can, and it's not considered bad practice. The function behaves just as if you use it in a global context. This also enables you to use arrays on functions which take several arguments.

See also:

- MDN: [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply): [`apply` and built-in functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#apply_and_built-in_functions)